# How to have the computer randomize statements with in a vbs?

Tags: vbscript

I been working on a .vbs for a modified version of the Paper, Rock, and Scissors game but have had nothing but error after error. Please be gentle on the the amount of but hurt as i am still very new to the language of .vbs here is what i have so far.

Right now as it stands the code looks as follows:

```
`'***********************************************************************
'Script Name: RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock.vbs
'Author: Chuck.Norris
'Created: 03/03/15
'Description: This script prompts the user to Play a game.
'***********************************************************************

'Formally declare variables used by the script before trying to use them
Option Explicit
Dim objWshShell, strAnswer, strCardImage, strResults, GetRandomNumber, intGetRandomNumber, strCounter

strCounter = 1
Do while (strCounter <= 5)
strCounter = strCounter + 1

'Create an instance of the WScript object in order to later use the popup method
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strResults = "None"

'Display the rules of the game
strAnswer = InputBox("Please type Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock." & _
         vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Rules:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _ 
         "1. Guess the same thing as the computer to tie." & vbCrLf & _
         "2. Paper covers rock and wins." & vbCrLf & _
         "3. Rock crushes lizard and wins." & vbCrLf & _
         "4. Lizard poisons Spock and wins." & vbCrLf & _ 
         "5. Spock smashes Scissors and wins." & vbCrLf & _ 
         "6. Scissors decapitates Lizard and wins." & vbCrLf & _ 
         "7. Lizard eats paper and wins." & vbCrLf & _ 
         "8. Paper disproves Spock and wins." & vbCrLf & _
         "9. Spock vaporizes Rock and wins." & vbCrLf & _ 
         "10. And as it always has...Rock crushes scissors and wins." & vbCrLf, "Let's Play a Game!")

'Time for the computer to randomly pick a choice 
Randomize
GetRandomNumber = Round(FormatNumber(Int((5 * Rnd) + 1)))
intGetRandomNumber = GetRandomNumber

If GetRandomNumber = 5 Then strCardImage = "Lizard"
If GetRandomNumber = 4 Then strCardImage = "Spock"
If GetRandomNumber = 3 Then strCardImage = "Rock"
If GetRandomNumber = 2 Then strCardImage = "Scissors"
If GetRandomNumber = 1 Then strCardImage = "Paper"

'When you select rock
If strAnswer = "rock" Then

 If intGetRandomNumber = 5 Then strResults = "You Win"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 4 Then strResults = "You Lose"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 3 Then strResults = "Tie"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 2 Then strResults = "You Win"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 1 Then strResults = "You Lose"

End If

'When you select scissors
If strAnswer = "scissors" Then

 If intGetRandomNumber = 5 Then strResults = "You Win"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 4 Then strResults = "You win"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 3 Then strResults = "You Lose"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 2 Then strResults = "Tie"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 1 Then strResults = "You Lose"

End If

'When you select paper
If strAnswer = "paper" Then

 If intGetRandomNumber = 5 Then strResults = "You Lose"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 4 Then strResults = "You Lose"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 3 Then strResults = "You Win"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 2 Then strResults = "You Win"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 1 Then strResults = "Tie"

End If

'When you select spock
If strAnswer = "spock" Then

 If intGetRandomNumber = 5 Then strResults = "You Lose"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 4 Then strResults = "Tie"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 3 Then strResults = "You Win"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 2 Then strResults = "You Win"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 1 Then strResults = "You Lose"

End If

'When you select lizard
If strAnswer = "lizard" Then

 If intGetRandomNumber = 5 Then strResults = "Tie"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 4 Then strResults = "You Lose"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 3 Then strResults = "You Lose"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 2 Then strResults = "You Win"
 If intGetRandomNumber = 1 Then strResults = "You Win"

End If

If strResults = "None" Then

 objWshShell.Popup "Sorry. Your answer was not recognized. " & _
     "Please type rock, paper, scissors, lizard, or spock in lower case letters."
  WScript.Quit
  End if

'Display the game's results so that the user can see if he or she won.
objWshShell.Popup "You picked: " & Space(12) & strAnswer & vbCrLf & _ 
    vbCrLf & "Computer picked: " & space(12) & strCardImage & vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & "=================" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Results: " & _ 
    strResults
Loop`
```

Script is working and i have learned in the process keep moving forward.

Comment: you need to ask better questions.  see [Ask]... `Can someone help me with my game?` is not the least bit specific at all.

Comment: Added more to the question @Plutonix

Comment: If you want help with errors, you need to supply the complete error message including the error number and the line raising the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Adding a double quote to

```
vbCrLf & =================" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Results: " & _
```

to get

```
vbCrLf & "=================" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Results: " & _
```

makes your script syntactically correct.

(2) Putting an `Option Explicit` at the top will force you to `Dim` the variables `GetRandomNumber` and `intGetRandomNumber`, and point out the (repeated) typo `strRults` for `strResults`.

(3) Your

```
intGetRandomNumber = GetRandomNumber = Round(FormatNumber(Int((5 * Rnd) + 1)))
```

does **not** assign the random number to `GetRandomNumber` and `intGetRandomNumber` but compares (empty) `GetRandomNumber` to that number and assigns the boolean result (False) to `intGetRandomNumber`. For just now use

```
GetRandomNumber = Round(FormatNumber(Int((5 * Rnd) + 1)))
intGetRandomNumber = GetRandomNumber
```

Evidence:

```
>> Dim a, b
>> b = a = 1
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(a)
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(b), CStr(b)
>>
Empty
Boolean False
```

That should give you a 'working' script.

P.S. What can be done to/with VBScript is determined by the Current Set of Knowledge and Skills (CSKS) of the programmer, not by the editor.

**Update wrt comment/last edit:**

Your last edit still contains

```
intGetRandomNumber = GetRandomNumber = Round(FormatNumber(Int((5 * Rnd) + 1)))
```

I told you why this can't possibly work and that you need to replace this by

```
GetRandomNumber = Round(FormatNumber(Int((5 * Rnd) + 1)))
intGetRandomNumber = GetRandomNumber
```

Comment: `GetRandomNumber = Round(FormatNumber(Int((5 * Rnd) + 1)))
intGetRandomNumber = GetRandomNumber`

Is still giving me a error.

Comment: @Chuck.Norris - What error?

Comment: That the variable GetRandomNumber is undefined  @Ekkehard.Horner

Comment: @Chuck.Norris - You didn't Dim those variables!

Comment: I did Dim them I just forgot to copy and paste here yesterday, I fell asleep buy I have been working hard trying to get it to work as I am still learning I got it to run. But when I give it any of responses like rock or paper it jumps straight to the strResults variable just giving me the None response each time.  @Ekkehard.Horner

Comment: I got it to work @Ekkehard.Horner thank you for  all your assistance on this it is greatly appreciated. I had a two or three typos i fixed and moved and spaced out the round from GetRandomNumber = Round that was togther for some reason. @ Ekkehard.Horner